# Java code below not show any errors in the code but it throw an Exception saying illegal options. So , what is missing?

Tags: java, weka

```
package cbr;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import weka.clusterers.ClusterEvaluation;
import weka.clusterers.FarthestFirst;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.filters.Filter;
import weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.Remove;
public class Cluster {
protected int m_ClusterCentroids;
protected Instances 
protected Instances m_instances;
protected int m_Seed;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Instances data = new Instances(new 
BufferedReader(new  
FileReader("FinalDatasetforCBSAPDS.arff")));
data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() -1);
Remove filter = new Remove();
filter.setAttributeIndices("" +(data.classIndex() + 1));
filter.setInputFormat(data);
Instances dataClusterer = Filter.useFilter(data, filter);
FarthestFirst clusterer = new FarthestFirst();
clusterer.setNumClusters(5);
clusterer.setSeed(5127); // set the seed size
String[] options = new String[2];
int nClusters = 5;
int seed = 5127;
options[0] = String.valueOf(nClusters);
options[1] = String.valueOf(seed);
clusterer.setOptions(options);           
ClusterEvaluation eval= new ClusterEvaluation();
eval.setClusterer(clusterer);
eval.evaluateClusterer(data);
System.out.println("# of clusters: " + 
eval.getNumClusters());
clusterer.buildClusterer(dataClusterer);
eval.setClusterer(clusterer);
eval.evaluateClusterer(data);
System.out.println(eval.clusterResultsToString());
Instances centroids = clusterer.getClusterCentroids();
int numclusters = clusterer.getNumClusters();
String filename = "Final_Dataset";
filename += "for_CBSAPDS";
filename += ".txt";
File file = new File(filename);
try (Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new 
FileWriter(file))) {
for (int i= 0; i<=5127; i++) {
for (int j= 0; j<numclusters; j++) {
String centroidsStr= centroids.instance(i).toString();
String[] to = centroidsStr.split(",");
writer.write(Integer.toString(i));
writer.write(",");
writer.write(data.instance(j) + "," + "case" + i + "," + (to[0]));
writer.write("\n");
}

}

System.out.println("\nInformation:");
}

}

}
```

This is the java code for farthestfirst clustering algorithm I wrote to integrate farthestfirst clustering algorithm with CBR. But it throws an Exception like:

Exception in thread ''main'' java.lang.Exception: illegal options: 5  527 
at weka.core.Utils.checkForRemainingOptions(Utils.java:505)  at weka.clusterers.FarthesFirst.setOptions(FarthestFirst.java:568)
at  cbr.Cluster.main(Cluster.java)

So I need help on this issues

Comment: first: is missing indentation - I can not understand that cade

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong arguments to your `setOptions(..)` method. [The API](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/clusterers/FarthestFirst.html#setOptions-java.lang.String:A-) states, that you can supply the parameters as following Strings: 
`"-N <number of clusters>"` and `"-S <seed>"`

So you need to construct your parameters to look like this, if you want to use the `setOption` method. However, this seems to be overhead, as this method does the same as `setSeed` and `setNumClusters` (that you are already using) so you might just get rid of the `setOptions(..)` method and the respective parameters.

Comment: I am very happy on the help you supplied to my question.